# Splitting a large XML file that contains multiple XML documents concatenated together

Tags: python, xml

My xml file contains information about multiple patents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE us-patent-grant SYSTEM "us-patent-grant-v45-2014-04-03.dtd" [ ]>
<us-patent-grant>
.
.
.
</us-patent-grant>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE us-patent-grant SYSTEM "us-patent-grant-v45-2014-04-03.dtd" [ ]>
<us-patent-grant>
.
.
.
</us-patent-grant>
```

I want to create a seperate xml file for each patent. The problem is the file is not valid XML document.I tried to do something like this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as x
path = r"C:\Users\XX\Downloads\ipg190423\ipg190423.xml"
d = []
s = ""
f = open(path)
for l in f:
    if l == "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n":
        if len(s)>0:
            d.append(s)
        s = ""
    s += l
d.append(s)
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could use regex to identify the

?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?

line. When you find it, you read the following lines into another string/file until the next occurrence or the end of file.
Or if you don#t mind reading the whole file in a string, you can then use the usual str.split('...')

```
with open('workfile') as f:
    data = f.read()
texts = data.split('?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?')
```

and with line by line

```
texts = list()
with open('workfile') as f:
    text.append(f.readline())
    if f.readline.find('?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?') > 0:
       list.append(text);
       text = ''
```

You will have then a list of text which you can write to individual files.

The code is not tested, so you might need to fix it